# dynamically Hide or visible false gridview Auto generated columns in asp.net in code behind?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to visible false for Autogenerated columns in

```
 mygrid.Columns[0].Visible = false
```

When I have used Above code that is 'Hiding Actual data column' in My database table data false
But I want visible false Autogenerated select and autogerated delete buttons.

```
Gridview1.AutogeneratedColumns.visible =false;
```

this Property is not their in Vs could please help me.

Comment: Add `gridview` markup in your question.

Answer (score 0):

For showing and hiding `Cell` controls you have to track [RowDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event of GridView

Answer (score 0):

This is right code :

```
  Gridview1.AutogeneratedColumns=false
```

Gridview.AutogeneratedColumns

Gets or sets a value indicating whether bound fields are automatically created for each field in the data source.

More information :
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.autogeneratecolumns(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.autogeneratecolumns%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)